# Method to front capitalized words

Tags: ruby

I am trying to move capitalized words to the front of the sentence. I expect to get this:

```
capsort(["a", "This", "test.", "Is"])
#=> ["This", "Is", "a", "test."]
capsort(["to", "return", "I" , "something", "Want", "It", "like", "this."])
#=> ["I", "Want", "It", "to", "return", "something", "like", "this."]
```

The key is maintaining the word order.

I feel like I'm very close.

```
def capsort(words)
  array_cap = []
  array_lowcase = []
  words.each { |x| x.start_with? ~/[A-Z]/ ? array_cap.push(x) : array_lowcase.push(x) }
  words= array_cap << array_lowcase
end
```

Curious to see what other elegant solutions might be.

Comment: What if you use a simple sort? `["a", "This", "test.", "Is"].sort` returns `=> ["Is", "This", "a", "test."]`

Comment: What do you want `capsort` to return for your example?  Please edit to add that.  `"string"` is not the best name for an array.

Comment: Your method is just doing [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) the hard way. Toss in `Array#flatten` and you're done.

Comment: It is *extremely* impolite to change your question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers. It makes the people who donated a portion of their free time to help you by doing *your* work for you, look like idiots.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I apologize sir. I'm new to Ruby and stack overflow, so the ethics and culture are still new. You essentially submitted a ".sort" though, so I can't imagine this wasted very much of your time. I'm the one who really looks like the fool for not wording my question properly. It's hard to say I "flipped 180" on the question too. I appended my original post with my desired output to better clarify and added "The key is maintaining the word order." You shouldn't be worried about looking like an idiot... your other code was nice, and your profile is impressive. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def capsort(words)
  words.partition{|s| s =~ /\A[A-Z]/}.flatten
end

capsort(["a", "This", "test.", "Is"])
# => ["This", "Is", "a", "test."]
capsort(["to", "return", "I" , "something", "Want", "It", "like", "this."])
# => ["I", "Want", "It", "to", "return", "something", "like", "this."]
```

Comment: Beautifully put sir (or madam)!

Comment: I'm not sure how "This" is before "Is"... I'm pretty sure that 'i' is before 't' in the alphabet.

Comment: @Anlek, the OP want to preserve the order of the capitalized words and of the non-capitalized words, as well as putting the former first in the array that is returned.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thank you for the explanation, that makes so much more sense! :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Actually, the OP completely changed the question 180° after several answers had already been submitted. First, he *did* want the array to be sorted. The [original title](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35167539/1) of the question was "Ruby method to **sort** capitalized words" (emphasis mine), the tags applied to the question were [tag:ruby] and [tag:sorting], and the name of the method was (and still is) `capsort`. There was no mention of preserving the order, and no testcases to suggest otherwise. The question is now completely different, invalidating all earlier answers.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You are completely right. So I had upvoted you from the earlier stage. I was committed in editing the question to clarify the OP's intention of changing the question, but I agree that the OP shouldn't have changed the question. I felt that you were going to complain at some point.

Comment: @Jörg, I was aware of that. I considered commenting on the question about  it having been changed, but thought readers would be aware of that from the OP's on your quesion. True, some readers may have missed the OPs comment, but I too was tired, and therefore a bit lazy.

Comment: Maybe we need a method `flat_partition`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't think it has much use. Sorting with an array (multiple keys) is much more natural as a use case.

Answer (score 7):

The question was changed radically, making my earlier answer completely wrong. Now, the answer is:

```
def capsort(strings)
  strings.partition(&/\p{Upper}/.method(:match)).flatten
end

capsort(["a", "This", "test.", "Is"])
# => ["This", "Is", "a", "test."]
```

My earlier answer was:

```
def capsort(strings)
  strings.sort
end

capsort(["a", "This", "test.", "Is"])
# => ["Is", "This", "a", "test."]
```

`'Z' < 'a' # => true`, there's nothing to be done.

Answer (score 2):

```
def capsort(words)
    caps = words.select{ |x| x =~ /^[A-Z]/ }
    lows = words.select{ |x| x !~ /^[A-Z]/ }
    caps.concat(lows)
end
```

Comment: I see nothing that deserves a downvote. Am I missing something? Note you could replace the body of the method with `[*words.select { |x| x =~ /^[A-Z]/ }, *words.reject { |x| x =~ /^[A-Z]/ }]`, though [Enumerable#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition), as used by @sawa, is more efficient.

Comment: The use of `^` gives a bad impression.

Comment: Ruby also has a [`!~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-21-7E) operator: `x !~ /^[A-Z]/`

Comment: There are most assuredly more efficient ways, and ways to fit it on one line. The question asked for elegant, so I went for the most readable way, since readability is the best kind of elegant. Grab the capitals. Do the opposite to grab the lowercase. Put them together. Anybody should be able to see what is happening without any ruby experience.